# Update if two conditions already is in table

Tags: python, sql

I have this python script with some SQL code, and I'm struggling on making a if-statement. I have two ID's, and if they already exist then the `Logtext` should be updated, and if they don't exist, then it should just make a new with all the information.

```py
TextJobName = str(JenkinsJobName)
TextBuildNr = str(JenkinsBuild)
TextJobId   = str(TestJobId)
# Security since Jenkin requires a username and code
urllib3.disable_warnings()
req = requests.get(JenkinsLog_URL, auth=(user, pw), verify=False)
# Puts the console text output in logText
logText = pymysql.escape_string(req.text)
sqlConnection = connectionObject.cursor()
SendingLogFile = f"INSERT INTO testreportingdebug.logtexts(LogTextData, LogID, BuildID, JenkinsJobName) VALUES('{logText}', '{TextJobId}', '{TextBuildNr}', '{TextJobName}');"
sqlConnection.execute(SendingLogFile)
```

How do i make something like this

```py
SendingLogFile = f"IF testreportingdebug.logtexts(LogID, BuildID) IS SAME AS VALUES('{TextJobId}', '{TextBuildNr}') THEN UPDATE testreportingdebug.logtexts(LogTextData) VALUES('{logText}')
ELSE 
INSERT INTO testreportingdebug.logtexts(LogTextData, LogID, BuildID, JenkinsJobName) 
VALUES('{logText}', '{TextJobId}', '{TextBuildNr}', '{TextJobName}');"
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, a SQL query formatted as *SQL*, and a clear explanation would all be helpful.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/ ?